# Groovy Rest/HTTP Request Native for use with Script Runner

Tags: rest, authentication, groovy, api-key

I am trying to build a simple Http Get request that requires me to submit an api key as authentication (api key as unsername and blank password). I have seen some solutions using the groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder library. However, the piece of code will need to be deployed in an evironment that does not allow for libraries. So I tried the following where  is the url of the website i am trying to reach:

```
// GET
def get = new URL("<url>").openConnection();
def getRC = get.getResponseCode();
println(getRC);
if(getRC.equals(200)) {
    println(get.getInputStream().getText());
}
```

As expected this returns error 400 since I do not include any authentication with the api key, so I tried the following where  is the api key:

```
def get = new URL("<url>");
def authString = "<api_key>:".getBytes().encodeBase64().toString();
def conn = get.openConnection();
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic ${authString}");
def getRC = conn.getResponseCode();
println(getRC);
println(conn.getInputStream().getText());
```

But I still get the 400 error. I tried picking up the request through Fiddler but it doesn't seem to be tracking it (executing Groovy code through GroovyConsole).

Answer (score 0):

The second approach works. My mistake was to not substitute spaces in the URL with % signs.